# Efficiently compute double sum

Tags: list-manipulation, summation, map

Is there a "Mathematica Way", like Map or Apply to compute the following double sum?

$\sum_{i=1}^{N_1}\sum_{j=1}^{N_2} m_i n_j \, f(\tau_{i} \gamma_{j})$

I have already stored the lists $m,n,\tau,\gamma$.

$m$ and $\tau$ are of length $N_1$ and $n$ and $\gamma$ of length $N_2$. So my approach was to use something like

```
Outer[f, τ, γ]
```

for the function map, and then

```
Total[Total[Outer[f, τ, γ]]]
```

but how do Ι multiply `m`and `n` into the sum?

EDIT: Undo Edit, figured out the bug in my code

Comment: I guess the time to beat is `Sum[m[[i]] n[[j]] f[tau[[i]], gamma[[j]]], {i, 1, n1}, {j, 1, n2}]`

Comment: If `f` is simple enough then `Compile` will likely give the best possible performance.  But it's not "Mathematica-like".

Comment: You could likewise do an `Outer[Times,m,n]` and then `Dot` that with your first `Outer` result. I don't know how that will be speedwise though.

Comment: Does Table/ParallelTable count as Mathematica-like?

Comment: ;) Thank you for your answers. For me Mathematica-like is to avoid for or while loops and to use fast built-in functions

Comment: this seems a miniscule bit faster..: Flatten[ Table[ m[[i]] n[[j]] , {i, n1}, {j, n2}] ].Flatten[Table[f[t[[i]],z[[j]]], {i, n1}, {j, n2}]].

Comment: Actually I missed the need for `Flatten`. This variant works. `AbsoluteTiming[Flatten[Outer[Times, m, n]].Flatten[ Outer[f, t, gamma]]]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your elements are in lists the fastest way is to use array operations. In the present case of an outer product one index, let's say "i", will not be expanded, on the other you want to thread.

To operate on a list the function needs the attribute `Listable`. The `Times` function, as many other internal ones, is already listable, that is

```
Times[{1,2,3},x] = {x, 2x, 3x}
```

You want to do the same with your function "f", e.g.

```
ClearAll[f]
SetAttributes[f, Listable]

f[{1,2,3},x] = {f[1, x], f[2, x], f[3, x]}
```

For the threading part you can use `MapThread` to "slide" through the list, e.g.

```
MapThread[#1 f[#2] &, {{a,b,c},{1,2,3}}] = {a f[1], b f[2], c f[3]}
```

Finally your code will look like this

```
ClearAll[f]
SetAttributes[f, Listable]
f[x_, y_] := x y
{m, n, t, g} = RandomReal[1, {4, 1000}];

Total@Total@MapThread[m #1 f[t #2] &, {n, g}]
```

---

A note about speed: usually threaded operation are much faster than element ones

```
In[27]:= 
Total@Total@MapThread[m #1 f[t, #2] &, {n, g}] // AbsoluteTiming
Total@Total[Outer[Times, m, n] Outer[f[#1, #2] &, t, g]] // AbsoluteTiming
Sum[m[[i]] n[[j]] f[t[[i]], g[[j]]], {i, 1, 1000}, {j, 1, 1000}] // AbsoluteTiming
ParallelSum[m[[i]] n[[j]] f[t[[i]], g[[j]]], {i, 1, 1000}, {j, 1, 1000}] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[27]= {0.797645, 62806.3}

Out[28]= {1.554886, 62806.3}

Out[29]= {2.933898, 62806.3}

Out[30]= {0.828527, 62806.3}
```

Thus always try to use them when possible.

Comment: I think it should be Total@Total@MapThread[m #1 f[t, #2] &, {n, g}], otherwise it didn't work for me

Comment: You are aware of the second argument of `Total[]`, I presume? `Total[(* stuff *), 2]` works nicely in particular...

Answer (score 1):

How about using `Table` or `ParallelTable` like this:

```
Total[ParallelTable[m[[i]] n[[j]] f[τ[[i]] γ[[j]]], {i, 1, N1}, {j, 1, N2}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You *almost* had it.You were right to use `Outer[]`; what you missed was to interpret the sum as an appropriate matrix multiplication. Observe:

```
Table[Subscript[m, i], {i, 5}].Outer[f, Table[Subscript[τ, i], {i, 5}],
                                        Table[Subscript[γ, j], {j, 4}]].
                               Table[Subscript[n, j], {j, 4}] == 
Sum[f[Subscript[τ, i], Subscript[γ, j]] Subscript[m, i] Subscript[n, j],
    {i, 5}, {j, 4}] // FullSimplify
   True
```